# How to change color of CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

How can I change the color of `CircularProgressIndicator`?

The value of the color is an instance of `Animation<Color>`, but I am hoping there is a simpler way to change the color without trouble of the animation.

Answer (score 395):

This worked for me:

```
CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white))
```

Comment: this one helped for linear progressindicator too thanks a lot

Comment: Thx! Since when AlwaysStoppedAnimation exists?

Comment: In Flutter 1.20.0.7.2.pre I get
`The argument type 'AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<Color>'`

Comment: works also with CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.orange))

Answer (score 140):

#### Three way to solve your problem

**1) Using `valueColor` property**

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
     valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
),
```

**2) Set `accentColor` in your main `MaterialApp` widget.**
This is best way because you dont want to set color all the time when you use `CircularProgressIndicator` widget

```
MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        home: MainPAge(),
        theme: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.blue),
),
```

**3) Using `Theme` Widget**

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(colorScheme: ColorScheme(
            primary: Colors.red,
            // You should set other properties too
        )),
      child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
)
```

Comment: accentColor does not exist anymore. According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/progressindicator/CircularProgressIndicator), the primaryColor of the MaterialTheme should probably be used. Though, this has no effect in my testing. Not sure if there is a replacement for Method 2, then. Method 1 still works, though. :-)

Answer (score 56):

**for a sigle color set,**

[image]

```
 CircularProgressIndicator(
     valueColor:AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
   );
```

**for multi color change/set.**

[image]

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      AnimationController animationController;
      @override
      void dispose() {
        // TODO: implement dispose
        super.dispose();
        animationController.dispose();
      }
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        animationController =
            AnimationController(duration: new Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
        animationController.repeat();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Color Change CircularProgressIndicator"),
          ),
          body:  Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: animationController
                  .drive(ColorTween(begin: Colors.blueAccent, end: Colors.red)),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: animation controller used is here is outdated, for the new one refer, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html

Answer (score 17):

`accentColor` can be used for foreground color of Widgets.It changes the color any foreground widgets including `circularprogressbar` You can use like this:

```
void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    title: 'Demo App',
    home: MainClass(),
    theme: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.black),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 14):

**backgroundColor** set light color it saw like light background color on the circle, **valueColor** it is loading color it will show compile loading circle over the gray color

```
 CircularProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor: Colors.gray,
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black)
        )
```

Answer (score 13):

Using `progressIndicatorTheme` allows to define a theme for progress indicator.

```
ThemeData(
      progressIndicatorTheme: ProgressIndicatorThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    )
```

Comment: This is best answer using ThemeData as the case study

Answer (score 11):

A theme is a widget that you can insert anywhere in your widget tree.
It overrides the current theme with custom values
Try this:

```
new Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.yellow),
      child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
```

reference: https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter?at=5a84cf9218f388e626a51c2d

Answer (score 7):

```
valueColor:new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.yellow),
```

Answer (score 6):

## ******`accentColor`** is deprecated and no longer works.****

To have it globally in ThemeData, set it like this:

**LIGHT THEME:**

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
                 colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                    primary: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                ),
```

**DARK THEME:**

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
                 colorScheme: ColorScheme(
                    primary: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                ),
```

**LOCALLY:**

Or if you want it only for that one widget locally, just set the property of the `CircularProgressIndicator` like this:

```dart
CircularProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor:Colors.white,
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.pink),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 4):

just write this code in your theme data of your app

```
    ThemeData(
        progressIndicatorTheme: ProgressIndicatorThemeData(
            color: Colors.grey.shade700,),)
```

Answer (score 3):

In `main.dart` set the theme `accentColor`, the `CircularProgressIndicator` will use that color

```
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red, **accentColor:  Colors.yellowAccent**),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: SplashPage()
));
```

Comment: This will also affect other system colors, which is obviously not what was asked.

Answer (score 3):

By default, it inherits accentColor from Themedata

```
  void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
                 primaryColor: Colors.blue,
                 accentColor:  Colors.blueAccent,
                 //This will be the color for CircularProgressIndicator color
               ),
  home: Homepage()
    ));
```

You can change this accentColor property with your new color.
Other way is using with predefined ThemeData like this

```
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                 accentColor:  Colors.blueAccent,
                 //change the color for CircularProgressIndicator color here
               ),
  home: Homepage()
    ));
```

Or else you can directly change this color property in CircularProgressIndicator as shown below

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
         valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change it globally, in latest version of flutter you should change `colorScheme`:

```
void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    title: 'App',
    home: Home(),
    theme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme(
                primary: Colors.red,
                // You should set other properties too
            )
        ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this--->

```dart
CircularProgressIndicator(
valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.grey[500]),)),
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
CircularProgressIndicator(
  backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
  semanticsLabel: 'Linear progress indicator',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
  color: Colors.yellow, // Change your color here
),
```

Comment: there's no `color` parameter in the `CircularProgressIndicator` class

Comment: Actually there is a color parameter! @ 
ABDERRAHMANE OUALI what version of the flutter SDK are you on?

Comment: @ABDERRAHMANE OUALI There is `color` parameter!

Answer (score -5):

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator app:indicatorColor="@color/primaryColor" />
```

Comment: please read the question. The user specified the "flutter" tag