# Flutter: change CircularProgressIndicator color

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to change `CircularProgressIndicator` color but unable to change here is the code
still showing blue color.

```
CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],strokeWidth: 2.0,)
```

I have tried with `theme` but it is also not working.

```
child: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]
            ),
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 2.0,),
      ),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075652/10956936

```
CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue))
```